# th:text works with an expression, but th:replace doesn't

Tags: thymeleaf

**Variable**

From the controller I sent:

```
model.addAttribute("theme", "holmes");
```

**html**

```
<!--<p th:text="${'themes/' + theme + '/general/footer::footer(theme=' + theme +')'}">test</p>-->

<footer th:replace="${'themes/' + theme + '/general/footer::footer(theme=' + theme +')'}">Footer</footer>
```

**Exception**

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [${'themes/' + theme + '/general/footer], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "themes/holmes/posts/postList" - line 25, col 9)
```

**Proof that the commented expression works**

[image]

**Problem**

The commented out expression works. But the uncommented one blows up.
To the best of my ability I understand that the compiler sees a string rather than an expression here.

I am keen to understand:

1. What the difference is between the commented and uncommented lines.
2. How to write the replacement expression correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close. This works for me:

```
<footer th:replace="'themes/' + ${theme} + '/general/footer' :: footer(theme=${theme})">Footer</footer>
```

The reason this works is (probably) because of the way the fragment specification syntax is evaluated:

```
templatename::selector
```

Each part on either side of the `::` needs to be handled as a separate component. Putting the `::` in the string (as in your example) misleads the Thymeleaf renderer. I asssume it tries to find a template whose name is the entire string (including the `::`) and the `selector` part is lost.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent 2 days tryng to solve this.